# How to split string in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Friends 
I want to split the one string after some specific symbol in java script(JS)
this this was dynamic come anything but i want to separate **it with = sign**

Like 
var string = "Hello = World"
i want to split it using = sign 
like

```
string[0] = Hello;
string[1] = World;
```

Please Give me a Solution.

Comment: Have you tried [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)?

Comment: `string.split("=")`